# Distributed workers that ensure a single instance of a task is running

Tags: locking, task, distributed, worker

I need to design a distributed system a scheduler sends tasks to workers in multiple nodes. Each task is assigned an id, and it could be executed more than once, scheduled by the scheduler (usually once per hour).

My only requirement is that a task with a specific id should not be executed twice at the same time by the cluster. I can think of a design where the scheduler holds a lock for each task id and sends the task to an appropriate worker. Once the worker has finished the lock should be released and the scheduler might schedule it again.

What should my design include to ensure this. I'm concerned about cases where a task is sent to a worker which starts the task but then fails to inform the scheduler about it.

What would be the best practice in this scenario to ensure that only a single instance of a job is always executed at a time?

Comment: If you are in java, take a look at ZooKeeper. It's a general purpose distributed state machine, but solves the really bad things about this kind of problems (like network interruptions, computer crashes) quite nicely and is easy to use (after getting used to it). Trying to implementing such a thing yourself can drive you crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a solution that implements a consensus protocol. Say - for example - that all your nodes in the cluster can communicate using the [Raft protocol](https://raft.github.io/). As such, whenever a node X would want to start working on a task Y it would attempt to commit a message `X starts working on Y`. Once such messages are committed to the log, all the nodes will see all the messages in the log in the same order.

When node X finishes or aborts the task it would attempt to commit `X no longer works on Y` so that another node can start/continue working on it.

It could happen that two nodes (X and Z) may try to commit their *start* messages concurrently, and the log would then look something like this:

```
...
N-1: ...
N+0: "X starts working on Y"
...
N+k: "Z starts working on Y"
...
```

But since there is no `X no longer works on Y` message between the N+0 and  N+k entry, every node (including Z) would know that Z must not start the work on Y.

The only remaining problem would be if node X got partitioned from the cluster before it can attempt to commit its `X no longer works on Y` for which I believe there is no perfect solution.

A work-around could be that X would try to periodically commit a message `X still works on Y at time T` and if no such message was committed to the log for some threshold duration, the cluster would assume that no one is working on that task anymore.

With this work-around however, you'd be allowing the possibility that two or more nodes will work on the same task (the partitioned node X and some new node that picks up the task after the timeout).

Answer (score 1):

After some thorough search, I came to the conclusion that this problem can be solved through a method called [fencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencing_(computing)).

In essence, when you suspect that a node (worker) failed, the only way to ensure that it will not corrupt the rest of the system is to provide a fence that will stop the node from accessing the shared resource you need to protect. That must be a radical method like resetting the machine that runs the failed process or setup a firewall rule that will prevent the process from accessing the shared resource. Once the fence is in place, then you can safely break the lock that was being held by the failed process and start a new process.

Comment: it may be a bit more complicated than this -- if your worker failed and it's box was reset, it doesn't mean some request (it issued before crashing) isn't currently traveling to another system (or inside of another system) and when it (after unspecified amount of time) reaches it's destination it may cause a side effect that will break your system. Very few systems were specifically designed to handle this kind of stuff (I recall an incident at github where packets were stuck in limbo for up to 90 seconds before taking effect)... So we typically use "sleep for X seconds and pray it will be ok"

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a relational database to store task metadata + proper isolation level (can't go wrong with serializable if performance is not your #1 priority).

SERIALIZABLE

> This isolation level specifies that all transactions occur in a completely isolated fashion; i.e., as if all transactions in the system had executed serially, one after the other. The DBMS may execute two or more transactions at the same time only if the illusion of serial execution can be maintained.

Use either optimistic or pessimistic locking should work too. https://learning-notes.mistermicheels.com/data/sql/optimistic-pessimistic-locking-sql/

In case you need a rerun of the task, simply update the metadata. (or I would recommend to create a new task with different metadata to keep track of its execution history)